# Condition to check previous next article post title

Tags: plugin-development, posts, post-meta

I have to modify post title at runtime and it should not affect related and previous, next link post titles. What other condition should I use for it with these:

```
    if(is_single() && in_the_loop()){       
    
        $abc .="<li >".$rdate."</li>";      
        
        $abc .="<li>Discontinued</li>";
        
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you explain more clearly, please, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @anton here you can see in  image tow boxes showing in red in title bottom, that should not be displayed in previous/ next titles. I have added them via `the_title` hook. How to prevent it in function

Comment: Share your code also please)

Comment: @anton check code

Comment: You can better achieve this by directly editing theme template to display what you want under the single post title instead of using "the_title" filter.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [get_next_post()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_next_post/) to check if next post exists

```
if(strlen(get_next_post()->post_title) > 0)
{
    //show your next post link
}
```

Try to use [get_previous_post()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_previous_post/) to check if previous post exists

```
if(strlen(get_previous_post()->post_title) > 0)
{
    //show your previous post link
}
```